# Cannot find module './routes/customer' in Node js mysql error

Tags: node.js

i am complete beginner of node js. i am making simple crud using node js mvc.when i am running a app
node snode index.js i got the error

```
   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'F:\stcrud\routes\customer.js'
Require stack:
- F:\stcrud\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)

F:\stcrud>node index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'F:\stcrud\routes\customer.js'
Require stack:
- F:\stcrud\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\stcrud\index.js:10:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'F:\\stcrud\\index.js' ]
}
```

complete code i have uploaded on github.i gave the link below.
https://github.com/raguram1986/node/find/main

Comment: You have to Install the package, run `npm install morgan` in the root folder.

Comment: now i got the error as Cannot find module 'express-myconnection' i uploaded error above

Comment: Cannot find module './routes/customer' in Node js mysql error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install all packages (besides the modules that are part of node) you are requiring, for example in your `index.js` I found `express`, `morgan`, `express-myconnection` modules.

Run these in the root folder:

```
npm install express
npm install morgan
npm install express-myconnection
```

**Update**

For the file path error:

I've tested your original code, and it worked with:

```
const customerRoutes = require('./routes/customer');
```

As an alternative, these are also worked:

```
const customerRoutes = require(path.join(__dirname, './routes/customer.js'));
const customerRoutes = require(path.resolve(__dirname, './routes/customer.js'));
```

**Steps I made to test your code**

1. git clone https://github.com/raguram1986/node.git
2. npm install express morgan mysql express-myconnection
3. node index.js

Install and run inside the root folder.

**Tip:** you can use `npm init` which will create a `package.json` file, it contains information about your program and the modules you installed, so next time an `npm install` is enough to install all the required packages.

Comment: i did it error gone but i got the anoher problem Cannot find module './routes/customer'  pls see my project in github what was the problem

Comment: const customerRoutes = require(path.resolve(__dirname, './routes/customer.js')); i called it index.js still same error Cannot find module './routes/customer'

Comment: const customerRoutes = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '/routes/customer.js')); i wrote it like thar same errror starting dot has been removed

Comment: which steps need to do again

Comment: Sorry, I can't, I'm updating my answer.

Comment: which steps need to do again

Comment: Cannot find module 'F:\stcrud\routes\customer.js'  this error i just got

Comment: const customerRoutes = require(path.resolve(__dirname, './routes/customer.js')); here i got the error again full error i update above pls check sir

Comment: The error states you declared `customerRoutes` twice or more, leave just one declaration (`const customerRoutes=...`).

Comment: i tried your code what u said this error Cannot find module 'F:\routes\customer.js' i couldn't solved

Comment: ya . i did it but Cannot find module 'F:\routes\customer.js' why this error was displayed

Comment: The last thing is to check if the folder and file exist.

Comment: routes\customer.js is there

Comment: thanks for your time sir i will try what you have said

Comment: not i did what u said same error Cannot find module 'F:\employeec\routes\customer.js'